Does the signature of a method create a dependency between the implementation of that method, and the code that invokes it?
I am reading Ousterhout's A Philosophy of Software Design. In Section 2.3, Outserhout writes:

The signature of a method creates a dependency between the implementation of that method and the code that invokes it: if a new parameter is added to a method, all of the invocations of that method must be modified to specify that parameter.

Does a method really create a dependency between the calling code and its implementation?
I see how the calling code becomes dependent on the signature, but surely the implementation is arbitrary; it could be unimplemented (ignoring the parameters entirely), and therefore not dependent on the signature at all.
Perhaps the author meant that the dependency exists spacially between the calling code and the implementation? I could agree with this, but I suspect the truth of this idea depends largely (perhaps entirely) on your personal model of how these ideas fit together.

Not in JavaScript…

"a dependency between a and b" does not say the same as "a dependency of a on b" / "… from a to b", it does not specify a direction.

I suspect Ousterhout just use "implementation" with a different meaning than what is usual. He uses implementation to mean the definition of the method as opposed to calling the method. The signature might be defined on an interface with no implementation at all in the usual sense.

I think the author made a poor choice of words. The signature of a method is to a method as an interface is to a class, so client code (callers) and the method's implementation are both dependent on the signature (really, it's dependency inversion at the function level). A good design is one that takes advantage of that, buy conceptualizing the method in some way that makes the signature more stable with respect to (some set of) changes then either the client code or the underlying implementation.

"I see how the calling code becomes dependent on the signature, but surely the implementation is arbitrary" - i only now noticed this bit. Yeah, technically, implementation can be pretty arbitrary, but most implementations will make some use of the parameters, and rely on their meaning (and that of the return type). If you already have an impl. that uses the params, you will have to change it if you arbitrarily change the param list - so, it depends on it. E.g., suppose you have a func that makes a rectangle, with params (x, y, width, height), and change that to (left, top, right, bottom).

To give your question more context, let us remember what Ousterhood is trying to explain in the section of the book. Let me cite the first sentence from the paragraph where you got your cite from:

For the purposes of this book, a dependency exists when a given piece of code cannot be understood and modified in isolation; the code relates in some way to other code, and the other code must be considered and/or modified if the given code is changed.

Then he gives a few examples, and one example is "two pieces A and B of code, where A calls a method from B".
Now to your question:

Does a method really create a dependency between the calling code and its implementation?

Yes, it does: the calling code becomes dependend on the method - on it's signature as well as on it's implementation.

When the signature changes, you clearly have to change the callers.

When the implementation changes, you may have to test if caller(s) now behave differently, maybe you have to change them as well, maybe not, but at least you have to consider it.


This is an unidirectional dependency: the called method does usually not become dependend on the caller.

I see how the calling code becomes dependent on the signature, but surely the implementation is arbitrary; it could be unimplemented (ignoring the parameters entirely), and therefore not dependent on the signature at all.

First, this is not what Ousterhout wrote. He did not say "the implementation of a method becomes dependend on its signature", I think you have misread that statement. Nevertheless, this is usually true, the implementation of a method depends typically on its signature. Sure, there are edge cases where parameters are superfluous and an implementation will not have to be changed when a method's signature changes, but at least one has check whether this is the case or not.
Note the chapter is about "Causes of complexity", which gives some examples how complexity is introduced into a software system by dependencies on a broad scale. Saying the "signature creates the dependency" is IMHO just a figure of speech, I would not read this too literally. The dependency is created by the caller calling the callee, and when we read the calling code, we identify the dependency by what we see from the callee: its signature.

could you comment on the situation when a method can not work without information provided via an argument? If new caller implementation lacks the information, would not that "break" the callee in a certain sense?

How can a caller be dependent on an implementation which might not exist? For instance, if calling code depends on a signature defined in an interface, then it is not dependent on that interface's implementation, because it might not exist. The implementation is totally decoupled from the calling code. Calling code can depend on a signature, but I still don't see how it can depend on an its implementation of which it may have zero to many. The whole point of the dependency injection concept to break dependency between calling code and implementation? 'depend on interfaces, not implementations'

"the calling code becomes dependent on the method - on it's signature as well as on it's implementation" - I would disagree with that. We write software with method calls precisely so that we do not depend on a particular implementation, the interface (type of the object, which includes the method signatures but not a concrete implementation) is an abstraction layer and a module boundary. Admittedly, the interface that we depend on also includes contracts (expectations) about what the method should do, which are seldom formalised.

@Bergi: I added some more context from Ousterhood what he is speaking about, then it might become clearer. Fact is, when code A calls a method from B, and B is changed in some way (interface or implementation), one has to consider that A might be influenced by the change in some way. Sometimes this is wanted, sometimes not, still the only guranteed way in A not becoming dependend on B is not to call the method at all.

@DocBrown: If the contract remains unchanged, but the content of the response is different due to a willful implementation change, then the baseline assumption should be that this change is a conscious one, not one of an unconfirmed risk of introducing bugs into consumers. That's not to say that this doesn't happen in real life, but it should not be a driving factor when considering dependencies. If a method implementation is updated, we can't reasonably be expected to prescribe any guideline to account for any manner of badly doing so.

@Flater: still a dependency exists when A calls B, and any change in B has some potential to influence the behaviour of A, maybe in a wanted, maybe in an unwanted manner. It is only a simplistic example what Ousterhood means by "dependency" in the context of that book, don't overinterpret it.

@Bergi, I don't agree. We write methods typically as a way of organising code, not so that "we don't depend on the implementation". It may be possible to vary the implementation without breaking the caller, but if that works, then it would probably have been just as possible to write the code inline and then vary it - in other words, the implementation is no more free to vary just because it sits behind a method call.

@Flater, with this concept of the code "contract", it is rarely clear exactly what the contract is, or where it is specified (if it is explicit at all). It is typically far easier to simply treat a single implementation as mandatory, and any change is assumed to potentially impugn other workings and therefore requires reanalysis and retesting.

@Steve: A contract is very essentially what in the question's quoted text is referred to as "a dependency between the implementation of that method and the code that invokes it". For a method, its contract is its signature. For a class, that's its non-private fields/properties/methods (including their signatures). Whether or not an explicit interface exists to help separate the contract from its implementation is an additional consideration, but a contract exists regardless of whether a corresponding interface exists, as a contract is a very generalized concept w.r.t. component interaction

@Flater, "For a method, its contract is its signature" - I don't agree with this. The method signature is only a narrow aspect of what a programmer would regard as the "contract". For example, if string String.ToUpper(string) suddenly started returning lowercase due to an implementation change, a programmer would regard the "contract" as different, even though the signature needn't change.

@Steve The quoted text in the question is not focusing on behavior, it is focusing on the blast radius of a change to the method signature. The cleanliness of code, which is the ultimate goal of the piece being discussed, is irrespective of the precise business rules. That's not to say that we as developers don't need to consider both, we obviously do as marrying the two is arguably the core premise of our role, but that doesn't mean that a guideline on code cleanliness needs to explicitly focus on application behavior at the same time.

The implementation includes the name, the parameter list, the return type, as well as the body of the method. Ignoring them in the body does not change the requirement that all the parameters are mentioned.

Can you expand on the idea that 'the implementation includes the parameter list'? Why does it? Does the implementation also include the return type?

@user3899725 yes, it includes all of those. plus the name. How would it not include those things?

Well, I am testing the idea that the implementation is dependent on the parameter list. Because the implementation includes parameters (I am not convinced that it does, but let's assume that is true), does that necessarily mean it is dependent on them? For example: if we say the return type is included in the implementation - and is therefore dependent on the return type - what if the implementation simply throws an exception and does nothing else. Is the implementation necessarily dependent on the parameters, return type, etc. simply because they are 'included'?

@user3899725 no, the implementation is all of the things I mentioned. Callers are dependant on the name, parameters and return type, and to some extent the semantics of the body. And in most languages, the return type is implicitly Type or thrown Exception or never finish, not just Type

I have no doubt that the caller is dependent on the signature. But the question is if there is a logical (not spacial) dependency between calling code and the implementation. The book suggests that there is. But my take on it is that the signature breaks dependency between calling code and implementation (isn't that the whole point?).

The signature is part of the implementation. You are implying the body of the method is the whole of the implementation, which is not a very common way of looking at it.

@user3899725 yes, for the body to use a parameter, it has to exist

So implementation = signature + body? If this the case, and since there is no dependency between the body and the caller, the author should have said that the signature creates a dependency between the signature and the calling code, which is a weird thing say since it is true by definition.

IMO the signature is a layer of indirection between the caller and the implementation. The signature can be defined independently of the implementation. In which case the implementation merely references the signature (the signature is not an integral component of the implementation). In this case the independently defined signature breaks dependency between a signature's caller and its implementation.

The key word you're looking for here is "contract" (or "interface", although this one is a bit more ambiguous for languages that have an interface keyword).
When two components interact with one another, they would ideally remain mostly independent of one another, each one being independently capable of changing its internal implementation without the other needing to be made aware of it. This is what we try to achieve using encapsulation and general clean coding.
However, there is an inevitable link between the two. Their interaction inherently means that one will call on the other in some way, using some syntax. Though it's not the only way, let's assume their interaction is that A calls one of B's methods.
In other words, somewhere in the A logic you will find myB.DoSomething(foo);. I can change the implementation of A, e.g. only calling this method in certain situations, without it impacting B's implementation of the DoSomething method itself. Similarly, I can change B's implementation of the DoSomething method, without that changing anything about A's logic (i.e. deciding when to call the method).
However, when I change the signature of the method, this inherently means that both A and B have to respond to this change. There's no way around that. The interaction is inherently shared between the two interacting components.

but surely the implementation is arbitrary; it could be unimplemented (ignoring the parameters entirely), and therefore not dependent on the signature at all

If you're going to ignore the newly added parameters, there's no point to adding these parameters in the first place. You're trying to come up with nonsensical edge cases to the advice.
However, in the interest of humoring your quest for edge cases:

If the added parameter is an optional one (e.g. C# allows for this), then it's possible that the consumer does not need to update their call.
If you change a method parameter's type in a way that the prior type can be implicitly casted to the newer type (e.g. int to float), the consumer does not need to update their call either.

That being said, if you're trying to learn things, I suggest you focus on what's being conveyed rather than jumping straight into looking for edge cases. Almost every rule has an edge case or exception, and while it is possible to define things in a way to account for more edge cases, this significantly complicates the learning material, which is detrimental to how easy it is to learn the core concept.

Where is comprehensive information about the "contract" stored? Is it something in source code? In separate documentation? In your mind?

@Steve: I'm not quite sure what your specific question is, and whether the seemingly facetious tone is intentional.

I disagree that "contract" is the same as "interface". I would say "contract" = "interface" + pre-conditions + post-conditions.

I'm not intending to be facetious, but I am hitting where I think it is going to hurt, because I think this notion of a "contract" is generally an ill-defined thing that exists largely in the mind of the beholder (i.e. it's not easy to thoroughly record, or share), and I also think that the vast majority of reasons why you would want to change an implementation are the same reasons why the "contract" itself would be changed on the same occasion.

@Steve Like many things, different contexts lead to different definitions. For the compiler, the contract is nothing more than the signature of a method call. For a consumer, it's the expectation of behavior. For an API, it's the combination of model structure and endpoint signature. The context of the quoted piece is one of encapsulation of the code (or lack thereof) whereby changes to the contract impact both the implementer and the consumer. Behaviour is irrelevant for the specific point being made.

@BartvanIngenSchenau: See above comment. I don't disagree with you but the precise definition changes when the context does, and this answer is working with the context as defined by the quoted text in the question.

@Flater, a problem for me is your introduction of the notion of a "contract". You admit it means all sorts of things to all sorts of people. You now mention what it can mean "for the compiler", "for the consumer", "for the API". But what does it mean for a practitioner designing software, like the OP? How helpful is it to introduce such a vague term? (1/2)

Another problem for me is the claim that "implementations can vary independently". This is a commonly repeated motif in various software discourse which I've heard many times in many places - the OP himself employs it. What you're really saying is that implementations can vary, provided the call signature is the same, and provided neither side cares about how, when, or if inputs map to outputs. Yet it would be silly to suggest that callers don't care how, when, or if inputs map to outputs. It's not sensible to repeat such claims which are valid only under unrealistic circumstances. (2/2)

@Steve: Your feedback is judging my answer as if it's otherwise context-free, as opposed to responding specifically to the context established by what OP is quoting. As to your second comment, I don't disagree that to a consumer the behavior of a dependency matters, but the behavior isn't what the quoted text is focusing on, it is purely addressing the breaking nature of a change to a method's signature. You're pulling in a thread that is not part of what OP is asking for clarification on.

@Flater, looking very carefully through the question, I'm struggling to see an interpretation where it is valid to say that an "implementation can vary independently of the caller". The book author Ousterhout seems to be saying the opposite. What I'm understanding him to say is that a caller acquires a responsibility to supply the necessary arguments or prerequisites of the call, and if the implementation changes in such a way that the method signature changes, then the caller must re-adapt to supply what is necessary. (1/3)

In this way the caller becomes "dependent" on the existing implementation, because a different implementation may alter the signature and make different demands of the caller (requiring the caller to change). I admit this inverts the typical view in which the caller is master and the callee the subordinate, but it does show that implementation cannot vary independently. (2/3)

I suspect you might also distinguish between changing the implementation and changing the interface (in terms of the method signature, in this case), but if the implementation dictates the signature change then its an irrelevant distinction, since the chain of dependencies connecting the caller and the callee implementation is still shown. (3/3)

@Steve "this notion of a "contract" is generally an ill-defined thing" - not if you define it well (as in, very precisely, clearly, at the appropriate level of abstraction) and if your team consists of decent modelers, so everyone is "on the same page" design-wise. The problem that comes up in the industry practice is that most teams are not like that, so what ends up happening is a lot of extraneous grind and perpetual work and rework, which is considered to be the normal state of affairs.

@Flater, I'm sorry to keep pressing, but the "point being made" by Ousterhout was that callers and implementations are interdependent. That is the central point, and is the OP's question, as I've understood it. Do you see it differently? My view is that such an interdependence between caller and implementation does exist, is quite normal and desirable, and although Ousterhout uses the signature to illustrate his point, such interdependence is not restricted to the signature, but permeates everything without specific limits. (1/3)

The relevance of stating this, is because in your second paragraph you say the "ideal" is to be able to vary implementations "independently". In my view that is not the ideal and is not the purpose at hand when designing methods. The purpose is to make (and keep) the interdependencies between different parts of the software amenable to human analysis (i.e. ensure interdependencies are not so complicated that we lose our grasp of them). (2/3)

It's a subtle but important point, because the goal is not to minimise interdependency for its own sake and strive towards the "ideal" of independence (since total independence would lead to disconnected parts with no common function), nor is the goal to maximise the scope for "independent" variability (which could just as well be zero), but to maximise understandability and minimise mental effort by ensuring a certain orderliness of interdependencies. (3/3)



The signature of a method creates a dependency between the
implementation of that method and the code that invokes it: if a new
parameter is added to a method, all of the invocations of that method
must be modified to specify that parameter.

Does a method really create a dependency between the calling code and
its implementation?
I see how the calling code becomes dependent on the signature, but
surely the implementation is arbitrary; it could be unimplemented
(ignoring the parameters entirely), and therefore not dependent on the
signature at all.

Consider the following (more clear) scenario of adding an extra parameter in the API. And having several separate implementations. Then it is clear that every implementation is dependent on the API.
Just this is meant, and using the scenario above instead of considering a signature and an implementation vaguely, abstractly, might be too unclear.
Consider also the solution: instead of adding an extra parameter to a signature that maybe already has several parameters, use a compound parameter type with fields.
Then the parameter type (class) will be extended by an extra parameter.
But usage and signature will not be changed. Implementation(s) can be tackled separately, as can be the callers by an additional type constructor.
